Why do I get a unique constraint violation error when updating a logical replica?
I have two docker containers with PostgreSQL. I want to replicate data from existing tables in a database called wiki. I have tried using pglogical and the native logical replication feature. However, when I try to insert data into a table in the second container, a message appears saying that there is a duplicate key.
Below are the configurations of my docker environment using native logical replication. I create two containers. The first one has a table called persons with three records and the second one has the same table without any records.
Environment:
Dockerfile - For both containers:
# Use the official PostgreSQL image as base
FROM postgres:16-bookworm

# Package installation
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install postgresql-16-pglogical iproute2 iputils-ping \
    && apt-get clean \
    && apt-get autoremove \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Copy the postgresql.conf to the appropriate directory
COPY postgresql.conf /etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf

# Copy the init-db.sh script to the initialization directory
COPY init-db.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-db.sh

# Override default Postgres config file
CMD ["postgres", "-c", "config_file=/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf"]

USER postgres

postgresql.conf - For both containers:
listen_addresses = '*'
port = 5432
max_wal_senders = 10
wal_level = logical
max_replication_slots = 10
shared_preload_libraries = 'pgoutput'

init-db.sh - Container cont-db1-01:
#!/bin/bash
set -e

psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname "$POSTGRES_DB" <<-EOSQL

-- Create table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS persons (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(100),
    age INT
);

-- Insert test data
INSERT INTO persons (name, age) VALUES ('Alice', 30);
INSERT INTO persons (name, age) VALUES ('Bob', 25);
INSERT INTO persons (name, age) VALUES ('Charlie', 35);

EOSQL

init-db.sh - Container cont-db2-01:
#!/bin/bash
set -e

psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname "$POSTGRES_DB" <<-EOSQL

-- Create table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS persons (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(100),
    age INT
);

EOSQL

docker-compose.yml:
version: '3.1'
services:
  db1:
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    container_name: cont-db1-01
    hostname: cont-db1-01
    build: ./db1
    image: db1:1.0
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: wiki
  db2:
    ports:
      - 5433:5432
    container_name: cont-db2-01
    hostname: cont-db2-01
    build: ./db2
    image: db2:1.0
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: wiki

Replication Configuration:
docker exec -it cont-db1-01 psql -U postgres -d wiki -c "
CREATE PUBLICATION pub_for_node1 FOR ALL TABLES;
"

docker exec -it cont-db2-01 psql -U postgres -d wiki -c "
CREATE PUBLICATION pub_for_node2 FOR ALL TABLES;
"

docker exec -it cont-db1-01 psql -U postgres -d wiki -c "
CREATE SUBSCRIPTION sub_to_node2 CONNECTION 'host=cont-db2-01 port=5432 dbname=wiki user=postgres password=postgres' PUBLICATION pub_for_node2;
"

docker exec -it cont-db2-01 psql -U postgres -d wiki -c "
CREATE SUBSCRIPTION sub_to_node1 CONNECTION 'host=cont-db1-01 port=5432 dbname=wiki user=postgres password=postgres' PUBLICATION pub_for_node1;
"

Tests:
docker exec -it cont-db1-01 psql -U postgres -d wiki -c "SELECT * FROM persons;"
 id |  name   | age 
----+---------+-----
  1 | Alice   |  30
  2 | Bob     |  25
  3 | Charlie |  35
(3 rows)

docker exec -it cont-db2-01 psql -U postgres -d wiki -c "SELECT * FROM persons;"
 id |  name   | age 
----+---------+-----
  1 | Alice   |  30
  2 | Bob     |  25
  3 | Charlie |  35
(3 rows)

The above two outputs show the data inserted into the persons table in the first container and its replication in the second container.
docker exec -it cont-db1-01 psql -U postgres -d wiki -c "INSERT INTO persons (name, age) VALUES ('Maria', 40);"
INSERT 0 1

docker exec -it cont-db1-01 psql -U postgres -d wiki -c "SELECT * FROM persons;"
 id |  name   | age 
----+---------+-----
  1 | Alice   |  30
  2 | Bob     |  25
  3 | Charlie |  35
  4 | Maria   |  40
(4 rows)

The insertion of a new record into the persons table of the first container was successful.
docker exec -it cont-db2-01 psql -U postgres -d wiki -c "INSERT INTO persons (name, age) VALUES ('Jose', 10);

"ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "persons_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.

The output above shows that when I try to insert a record into the people table in the second container, it says there is a duplicate key. I want the replication to be truly bidirectional. I have searched extensively on the internet and have not been able to resolve this issue.
I would like to use database replication in the Wiki.js system. There would be two Wiki applications, each accessing a database. I would use the second application in case the first one fails.

The answer is simple: the SERIAL pseudo data type is backed by a sequence, and the sequence modifications are not replicated, meaning that each server maintains its own copy of the sequence. When you run your insert on the second node without providing an explicit value for id, the server attempts to use the value 1, because the sequence has never been used on that server before.
Generally, "truly bidirectional" replication is not easy to implement using the tools available in the base PostgreSQL. Actually, it is not easy to implement, period.
